# Is it possible to manually set a cookie with Dio in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, interceptor, dio

Im using cookieJar interceptor with Dio, but is it also possible to manually add a cookie on top of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 final BaseOptions dioBaseOptions = BaseOptions(
baseUrl: 'http://192.168.1.19',
headers: {
  'Host': "api.radio.test",
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Cookie': 'XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM',
},
);
```

Comment: Will you add an explanation